# Why does the Stack Overflow menu say "PUBLIC?

Tags: discussion, left-navigation

I haven't seen this on any of the other sites.

[image: "]

Comment: Not sure, but maybe since using SO Teams shows more options which aren't _PUBLIC_? The _locked_ symbol is much of a hint.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because Stack Overflow Teams are **private.**

For those who have Stack Overflow Teams, it seamlessly integrates into the left-hand menu sidebar along with Stack Overflow.  When those who have Stack Overflow Teams post to Stack Overflow, they get a warning dialog indicating that their post is about to be made public, just in case they actually intended to post to their private Stack Overflow Teams site.

Comment: For those who don't have teams it serves no purpose though

Comment: Other than to annoy the pedants, which is a worthy cause.

Comment: Would it not make sense for the teams advert to be placed under a "PRIVATE" label then?

Comment: It would make sense to detect the presence of Stack Overflow Teams and hide the PUBLIC tag if it's not present. I totally agree with the OP, this is out-of-place and confusing.

Answer (score 13):

As suggested in the comments by πάντα ῥεῖ, this is part of the design for teams. It's to help distinguish between what is private to a team, and public to the world.

[image]        [image]

Comment: @kkarakk … That _is_ a screenshot of the private variant.

Comment: oh so it still says public above? i thought stack had a private variant with tags, users, jobs etc for internal use

Comment: @kkarakk when you entre a team it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhOn0.png - you have tags and users, but not jobs.

Comment: yeah that's the screenshot i wanted to see, you can't see that unless you sign up for teams...

Comment: @kkarakk added the screenshot to the post