# Why does stackoverflow.com label the questions link "Stack Overflow" and not "Questions" like all the other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

(I'm sure this question has been asked before - or there was a post explaining the reasons behind it - but I couldn't find it.)

The link is the same in both cases (to the `/questions` URL on the respective site). I do find the SO UI confusing in this regard (OK, I'm *used* to it) as there is no *visible* link to "Questions".

[image: StackOverflow vs ServerFault]

The fact that the "questions" link is selected at all when you aren't actually on the list-of-questions page is also a bit weird/confusing in my opinion. Visually, it doesn't look like an active link.

Comment: Probably to differentiate from “teams”.

Comment: Related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381342/10945545

Comment: Although if it's another "teams differentiation" thing then it's unnecessarily screwing with the UI for the vast majority of "normal" users IMO. But the "differentiation" would seem to be already made with the "PUBLIC" _side heading_, "TEAMS" is displayed below this. "Stack Overflow" itself is a _heading_, _Questions_ is subordinate to this - they aren't necessarily the same thing. As seen in the screenshot, "Stack Overflow" is already shown at the top, so it's "Stack Overflow" _within_ "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: As a Teams user… this is still annoying. Why can't it just say "Questions" with a little globe next to it?

Comment: Also related, this is a request to fix it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369416/change-the-title-of-the-sidebar-option-for-questions-to-questions-as-on-mse-an, ignored for 10 months so far...

Comment: Also related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369485/change-the-icon-and-improve-the-new-left-nav

Comment: Because the Stack Overflow UI is a huge mess. Unrelated, but I had to use Google a few days ago to find my past applications on jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The powers that be did eventually see the light...

[image: Updated StackOverflow UI showing "Questions" instead of "StackOverflow"]

<sup>(I believe this was covered in a blog article / meta post, although I can't seem to find it?)</sup>